# CGImageRelease causing crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage

I am using AGImagePickerController to pick multiple pictures from album, and then push the selected assets to a viewController where it tries to convert each asset into an UIImage.
However, I found out that if I selected more than 20 images, I will start to get memory low warning and the app exited. Here is my code of the conversion

```
for(int i =0 ; i < [self.selectedPictures count] ; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"Object %d",i);
    ALAsset *asset = [self.selectedPictures objectAtIndex:i];
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
    UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref scale:[rep scale] orientation:(UIImageOrientation)[rep orientation]];
    float newHeight = anImage.size.height / (anImage.size.width / 1280);

    UIImage *resizedImage = [anImage resizedImageWithContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit bounds:CGSizeMake(newHeight, 1280.f) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];

    UIImage *resizedThumbnailImage = [anImage resizedImageWithContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill bounds:CGSizeMake(290.0f, 300.f) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];

    // JPEG to decrease file size and enable faster uploads & downloads
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resizedImage, 0.6f);
    //NSData *thumbnailImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbnailImage);
    NSData *thumbnailImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resizedThumbnailImage, 0.6f);


    PFFile *photoFile = [PFFile fileWithData:imageData];
    PFFile *thumbnailFile = [PFFile fileWithData:thumbnailImageData];

    [photoFile saveinbackground];
    [thumbnailFile saveinbackground];
}
```

So i figured out that I should add CGImageRelease(iref); after anImage to release the iref, and the memory warning is gone. However, my app will crash after the last asset is converted to UIImage. And so far i could not find out why it is crashing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a way to fix this.
use `@autoreleasepool`

Comment: Your question was about why the crash is happening and your answer is no way related to that. Usage of @ autoreleasepool will never fix your crash. You should have put this as a separate question and marked as answer instead of unaccepting the correct answer which solved your crash.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be doing `CGImageRelease(iref);` unless you use `CGImageCreate`, 
`CGImageCreateCopy` or `CGImageRetain`. That is the reason why it is crashing.

Comment: so what is the better way of creating a UIImage out of an ALAsset?

Comment: Unfortunately you might have to rethink about your design. If you load too many images in memory at a time, it will show this warning. You might have to design it in such a way that, only the required number of images are there at any point of time and once the use is over you should release or equate to nil.

Comment: so equating anImage to nil can cause iref to be released too?

Comment: I think I tried to equate it to nil as soon as i convert the uIImage to NSDATA, but I still get memory warning

Comment: Is it really required to convert all objects in self.selectedPictures at the same time? Probably you might have to do only the required images at a time and rest of them can be done whenever required. While doing that you can empty the earlier UIImages. I am not sure about what your app is all about, so it is really difficult to comment on the architecture.

Comment: i have to convert all of them to UIImage, because after the user selected the pictures and pushed to this viewController, I will start running background uploading of these pictures, so I will need to convert them to UIImage, resize, and change them to NSData and upload.

Comment: How about converting only while uploading that particular image? Or are you sending all the images at the same time?

Comment: i just updated my code with more logic, so i basically convert to uIImage and do the upload right after it

Comment: I am not sure how all these will work in ARC, probably try to set UIImage objects = nil after PFFile *photoFile = ... lines.

Comment: @VincentYiu, If my answer has fixed your crash, can you please accept it?